# Completing the solution for Baby Rudin Chapter 7 Exercise 4

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Baby Rudin Chapter 7 Exercise 4

> Consider
> \begin{equation*}
>     f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2x}
> \end{equation*}
> For what values of $x$ does the series converge absolutely? On what intervals does it converge uniformly? On what intervals does it fail to converge uniformly? Is $f$ continuous wherever the series converges? Is $f$ bounded?

Can someone please provide some hints on how this problem can be solved? Based on a few sketches for certain values of $n$, I think $f(x)$ is unbounded, but I am having trouble showing that rigorously. Please don't provide complete solutions, I'd much rather fill in the details of the hints. Thanks.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It's $\mathbb{R}$. The entire problem is situated in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Look at $f(0)$.

Comment: At $f(0) = 1+1+1+\dots$. $f$ is clearly unbounded at $x=0$. Is this argument sufficient to prove that $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Unless you’re allowing $\pm\infty$ as values, $f$ isn’t even defined on all of $\Bbb R$. If you are allowing those values, then it’s defined but unbounded.

Comment: The domain is most likely the $x$s for which it converges, but I will wait for OP to confirm.

Comment: @Randall No domain was specified in the question but Ch. 7 in Rudin deals only with $\mathbb{R}$, so I assumed that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. I've edited my post to include the full, original question from Rudin.

Comment: It appears that my interpretation was the intention.

Comment: @Randall That might be the case, I am not sure. Can we use this new information to show that $f$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer: To show that $f$ is unbounded note that $f(\frac 1 {k^{4}}) \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac {k^{4}} {k^{4}+n^{2}} \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac {k^{4}} {k^{4}+k^{2}} =\frac {k^{5}} {k^{4}+k^{2}} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

EDIT
The series converges for any $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0,-1,-\frac 1 {2^{2}},-\frac  1{ 3^{2}},...\}$. It converges uniformly on the intersection of  $\{x: |x|>\epsilon\}$  with $\mathbb R \setminus \{0,-1,-\frac 1 {2^{2}},-\frac  1{ 3^{2}},...\}$ for any positve number $\epsilon$ (by comparison with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$). This also implies that $f$ is continuous  on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0,-1,-\frac 1 {2^{2}},-\frac  1{ 3^{2}},...\}$.

Comment: What exactly is $k$? Is it just a real number? Did you introduce $k$ because you wanted to work with the partial sum of $f(x)$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson The inequality I wrote is true for any pisitve integer $k$. So I have produced a sequence of numbers in the domain of $f$ such that the values of $f$ at these points tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Does the first part of your solution imply that $f\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Yes, exactly.

Comment: I think I finally understood the complete solution, thanks!